# pushing the data automatically from the queue to UI in JAVA

Tags: java, list, queue, push

I have a queue.When the messages on the queue are consumed i set the messages in a list and get it in the UI/jsp page.I have run the UI page periodically so that whenever the messages are consumed and set in a list then i can show them in the UI without refreshing.

But i dont want to update the UI periodically,instead whenever the new messages are set in a list,i want those new messages to display on the UI automatically.

I have no idea how to do this.Somebody help me.
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: What programming language/platform are you using?

Answer (score 0):

maintain a count for the number of messages in the list and periodically compare it with the length of the list.
when any new message will be inserted in the list, this count will be less than the length of the (updated) message list, hence update the UI component of your application.

Comment: what about setting a listener.i want to do it this way but dont know how to do it

Comment: adding a listener is also a good way of doing it. look at the [observer design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) for more information about it.
contact me if you need more help on it.